# Designing a sawtooth VCO

Tags: integrator, vco, sawtooth-waveform

Beginner here. I am trying to build a sawtooth VCO that runs on 5V, based on an op-amp integrator. See the design and output (V<sub>out</sub> of the op-amp) below.

[image]

For this circuit, the input voltage needs to be in the range [0V, 2.5V] (e.g. 2.49V) so that the output of the integrator rises. When the output reaches the threshold for the inverter, it makes the output drop to zero very quickly, and the cycle repeats.

However, I would like my input voltage to be in the range [2.5V, 5V] instead of [0, 2.5V]. I would like and expect that the output starts at 5V, and then gradually drops to the threshold of inverter, and then quickly rises to 5V again, producing a (descending) sawtooth. Is it possible to alter the circuit to accomplish this?

(Of course, it should be possible to convert the range [0V, 2.5V] to [2.5V, 5V] using an extra op-amp, but I would like to avoid this as it seems there should be a simpler solution.)

Comment: You need to find an op-amp that meets this requirement i.e. it needs to have rail-to-rail output characteristics and likely have rail-to-rail on the inputs. Do you have one in mind? Of course, if the op-amp power rail isn't 5 volts and 0 volts then, you need to say so.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks! Can you explain why/what is the difference?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the circuit.

Comment: Try to remove one inverter and use the NPN to pull IN- to GND.